# Redirect a specific file type from one directory to another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirecting only the jpg and png image files from a specific directory that has other file types that need to remain.

As a test, I tried this and other variations without success to move only the jpg.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\.jpg$ http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/redirected_media/$1.jpg
```

How can I redirect only the jpg and png image files using htaccess without affecting the other file types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that, in your `.../uploads/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /wp-content/uploads/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png))$ redirected_media/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If redirect it's not for the same server:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png))$ http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/redirected_media/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  I have added this to the .htaccess in the /uploads/ directory and the file types are redirected, but the URL isn't correct.  It is rewriting as follows --> http://www.example.com/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/redirected_media/test.jpg

Comment: With my second RewriteRule (only !) ? It's not possible, because I use absolute URL...

Comment: Apologies, not sure what happened but it must have cached my first attempt.  All is working now.  Thanks!